# Gzipping removed file signature signed by codesign in MacOS

Tags: macos, gzip, digital-signature, codesign, gunzip

I sign a file with codesign. Verify its signature - says it is correct, but when I gzip and ungzip it, the signature gets removed.
Here are the commands I try.

`>codesign -s "<identity>" -f -v --timestamp --options runtime example.app`

`>codesign -v --verbose example.app`

`example.app: valid on disk example.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement`

`>gzip example.app`

`>gunzip example.app.gz`

`>codesign -v --verbose example.app`

`example.app: code object is not signed at all`

The reason I want to do this, I want to provide codesigning over the network, and for sending it over the network I am planning to archive it so that the signature is retained.

How can I retain the signature if I want to send it over the network?

Comment: Is file.code a bundled app or a command line utility? I'm betting a command line utility?

Comment: It is an app, but I think it does not matter much as codesign can sign any type of file

Comment: example.app is a file? Usually whatever.app is a directory.

Comment: yes, that is a directory, but codesign does not care, it can sign .app, .dmg or any other thing